# JSON Object Array no spaces after comma

Tags: php, json

Here is my json array: **Updated**

```
    {
  "Title": "Limitless",
  "Year": "2011",
  "Rated": "PG-13",
  "Released": "2011-03-18",
  "Runtime": 105,

  "Actors": [
    "Bradley Cooper",
    "Robert De Niro",
    "Abbie Cornish",
    "Andrew Howard"
  ]

}
```

Here is my php return:

```
return response()->json($movie);
```

The Jquery:

```
$("#stars").val(data.Actors); //Nothing fancy about this. Just outputting data to an input field.
```

Result:

```
Bradley Cooper,Robert De Niro,Abbie Cornish,Andrew Howard
```

Why are there no spaces in between the names/comma's? Is there a way to achieve this without/with regex? Or is it a parsing error?

Comment: what is a "Json object array"?? How did you produce the first output, hence what is this in reality?

Comment: @Jeff I maybe confusing this too much. I have an array of json which is now updated above with a better readability. I am outputting that to a text field using jQuery (getting that via ajax call to my controller and the above jquery is used in my ajax success). But the problem is that the comma does not have spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be writing it as

```
$("#stars").val(data.Actors.join(', '))
```

Comment: Separator is not defined?

Comment: Updated the answer with seperator value.. i.e. `", "`

Comment: So this is an array join correct? So we are saying, join the arrays with `, ` comma and a space.

Comment: Yes exactly, `$("#stars")` is a textbox, and it can't simply show array.. so internally it's doing array.join with just comma...

if you want comma with space, you need to do it like this..

Comment: So here is a thought. Now my data is dynamic. It may sometimes be an array. Sometimes its just one single json. So in that case, it is sure to throw an error correct? `join is not a function`. How would I resolve this?

Comment: so in that case you can simply add if else condition.. `if(Array.isArray(data.Actors)) .... else return data.Actor`

Comment: That I am aware of. Is there a shorter way than using if else? I mean without sacrificing a lot of space. But yes. This works. +1000

Comment: No you have to write if else. you can try creating extension method jsonval eg.`$("#stars").jsonval(data.Actors)`. this way you don't need to write if else everytime

Comment: Yeah that is helpful. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this... Implode with `comma space`.

Snippet

```
return response()->json(implode(', ', $movie->Actors));
```

We have imploded with `,` (comma + space)

Comment: It is a JSON Object. Hence will not work with `str_replace`

Comment: This is a good solution too. But I think I will go for the above solution. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @BasicBud Yeah... This is server side(php) solution, and above is client side (jQuery).

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. Thanks mate :)